# How many words are required for What3Words?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

This is just curiosity / a personal exercise.

[What3Words](https://what3words.com/) allocates every 3m x 3m square on the Earth a unique set of 3 words. I tried to work out how many words are required, but got a bit stuck.

$$
Area
    = 510 \times 10^6 km^2 
    = 5.1 \times 10^{14} m^2
    => ~ 5.4 \times 10^{14} m^2
$$

(rounding up to make the next step easier!)

And so there are ~ $6\times10^{13}$ 3m x 3m squares.

I *assumed* I could use the equation to calculate number of combinations to find the number of words needed:

$$
_nC_r = \frac{n!}{r! (n - r)!}
$$

where $r$ is 3, and total number of combinations is the number of squares: $6\times10^{13}$

$$
6\times10^{13} = \frac{n!}{3! (n - 3)!}
$$
$$
6\times10^{13} = \frac{(n)(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)!}{3! (n - 3)!}
$$
$$
n^3 - 3n^2 + 2n - (36\times10^{13}) = 0
$$

... and then, I can't work out the first factor to use to solve the cubic equation, I'm not sure I've ever had to solve a cubic eqtn with a non-integer factor and none of the tutorials I've found have helped.

(And, my stats is also not good enough for me to be convinced this is the correct equation to use anyway!)

Any hints as to the next step would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the words ordered? meaning is "Chris.W" the same as "W.Chris"?

Comment: @Phicar no, they're not :) so, `maths.web.mug` is a different location to `maths.mug.web`

Comment: I think they also allow three equal words (e.g. maths.maths.maths is in the South China Sea), so the number of possible combinations is just $n^3$, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there! Your equation is not correct tho, cause you need an order in the words. So the right inequality is $$3!\cdot\binom{n}{3}\geq 6\cdot 10^{13},$$
which is $$n(n-1)(n-2)\geq 6\cdot 10^{13}.$$ Now, you can depress it (actual math term) meaning that you can make a change of variable to make your polynomial of the form $x^3+px+q$ by doing the change of variable $x+1=n$ getting
$$(x+1)\cdot x\cdot (x-1)=x^3-x\geq 6\cdot 10^{13},$$
now you can use [Cardano's formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula)
getting
$$x=\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 10^{13}+\sqrt{9\cdot 10^{26}-\frac{1}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{3\cdot 10^{13}-\sqrt{9\cdot 10^{26}-\frac{1}{27}}}=39148.67,$$
so $n=39149.67$ so take $n=39150.$

Comment: thanks! And, as verification, wikipedia says that W3W uses 40000 words!

Comment: @ChrisW You are welcome! Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Seems simpler to say, if the whole area of the globe is about $5\times10^{14}$ square metres, then you need about $6 \times 10^{13}$ squares.

If the number of squares is large, the number of words required will be very near to the cube root of this number.  This means about $39,000$ words.

OK?

Comment: In fact I think this is more correct, because the combinations can be three equal words too. So the three words are independent and ordered, so the number of all combinations is $n^3$, or isn't it?